# service granularity

Tags: soa

What is the best way to manage domain specific services?  For eg: In a Financial domain, Should I have a global service "AccountCreation" or "CheckingAccountCreation", "CreditcardAccountreation" etc.

I am struggling whether to keep them at global level or keep them at the product level. what is the best approach?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably focus in the data first: what data is there, and what data needs to stay consistent.  Then focus on what the behaviours around that data are.

> In a Financial domain, Should I have a global service "AccountCreation" or "CheckingAccountCreation", "CreditcardAccountreation" etc.

In this example, I would say that you have an "account" service, because you clearly have some accounts - and you probably have to ensure that, eg, you don't duplicate account numbers, apply anti-fraud rules, manage the workflow of creation, etc.

Your examples identify some behaviours: create a checking account, create a credit card account.  Those would appropriately be commands that you send to the service, because they result in mutation of the data that the service owns.

If you add a "customer" service, though, that would be distinct from the accounts service: it doesn't have to be consistent with the account service, just to have a reference from accounts to customers by ID.

You also generally don't have shared behaviour that touches both parts - updating data about a customer shouldn't touch the details of their accounts (directly), and updating an account doesn't change the details of a customer.

You might have business rules in one service that change another, such as the account service listening for "a customer became a student" announced by the customer service, and then doing some internal processing.

Comment: +1 to this answer. Focus on the data. Put data that needs to be transactionally consistent together. Once you do that analysis and have those buckets of data together, your services will show themselves.